# Invocation code list is empty in OpenX (Revive Adserver)

Tags: php, openx

I have set the OpenX server and I am trying to generate a test ad. I have followed the steps mention and added advertiser, campaign and banners. I have also added a website, a Zone and added the banners to the zone.

Now when I am trying to generate the Invocation Code, the dropdown for selecting the type of invocation in coming empty. I have searched and could not find the answer. Can any one tell what might be wrong here? Thanks for your time. Below is the screen shot for the Invocation Code screen.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](http://www.adserveropenx.com/couldnt-get-invocation-tags-since-upgrade-done/) should help you out. Your plugins aren't being read as installed.

They are located in [openX path]/etc/plugins/openX/openXInvocationTags.zip.
Here is how to install them:

1. Plugins are located in `[openX path]/etc/plugins/`
2. You can download the invocation code plugin directly from your server by going to `http://yourserver.com/etc/plugins/openXInvocationTags.zip`
3. To install them, switch to the administrator account and go to the Plugins tab
4. Upload the plugin ZIP file you just downloaded

Here you go!

Comment: link-only answers are frowned upon here, maybe you should describe what's at the link